# send from client side to google apps script (server) base64 string

Tags: javascript, http, web, network-programming, client

I have this base64 string that represents a picture that I need to send to the server. All of the ajax requests just append the data to the query string to send to the server through the url and a query string/url sort of has a limit of 2,000 characters. Well my base64 string is around 97,000 characters so how do I get this thing over to the server?

POST - this would use url and restrict to 2000 characters...right?
GET - same as post...right?

what else could I do? Convert it to a blob? what would you do if you knew what you're were doing.. because I dont lol

thanks for your time!

Edit:

I think I ended up doing something like

```
              <form id="gform" method="POST" action="http://script.google.com/someScriptHash">
                <fieldset>
                  <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message Body"></textarea>
                </fieldset>
                <button id="sendEmail">Send</button>
              </form>
```

Then with javascript after setting the data within the form I submitted it with jquery like

```
$(gForm).submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using FormData object, its pretty straightforward, you can find clean and slick tutorial [here](https://coderwall.com/p/p-n7eq/file-uploads-with-jquery-html5-and-formdata).

Comment: from what I saw, this strategy 'serializes' the data (converts from form data to a key value pair string for url) into a query string, which is part of the url which is the problem - I cant request a 90,000 character url. Or am I totally wrong

Answer (score 1):

Use json to post the data:

```js
fetch('url', {
  method: 'post'
  headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),
  body: JSON.stringify({'payload': 'base64str'})
})
```

Comment: I got this error `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: I would be fine with disabling CORS, Im looking right now to find how to do that

Comment: @CotyEmbry you need to use the init { mode: 'cors' }. On the server side, it depends what backend you use, but you need to enable cors for domains and allow the Headers 'Content-Type' and 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'.

Comment: how would I enable cors for domains and also change those headers, in the response object its self?? Like set those headers on the response object just like you set the headers on the request object or is there something more to it? Also, part of my question was that my backend was/is google apps script so its executed in the google cloud I guess? Im not 100% though